# Как обновлять окно в PySimpleGUI в реальном времени

Tags: python, sql-server, pysimplegui

у меня есть такой код

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime        
connection = pyodbc.connect(("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=*******;Database=Test1;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID=sa;PWD=*******8"))
dbCursor = connection.cursor()
sg.theme('dark grey 9')
now = datetime.now()
Datatime = datetime.now()
print(datetime.now())          
def UpdateList():
    dbCursor.execute("select Tovar from BazaMSK")
    data = dbCursor.fetchall()
    new_list = ['']
    for word in data:
        new_str = ''
        for w in word:
            if w.isalpha():
                new_str += w
        new_list.append(new_str)
    new_str = ','.join(w for w in new_list if w)
    return new_list      
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Введите товар'),sg.Listbox(UpdateList(), size=(8,15), key='-KTovar1-'),sg.InputText(size=(50,6),key='-KTovar2-')],
    [sg.Text('Количество товара'),sg.InputText(size=(8,3),key='-KCountTovar-')],
    [sg.Output(size=(88, 20),key="-KInputText-")],
    [sg.Submit("Сохранить"), sg.Cancel("Обновить")]
]
window = sg.Window('Поставки', layout)   
#Тут надо обновить список чтобы можно было выбрать в интерфейсе новое значение
event, values = window.read()
while event not in (None,"Exit"):
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Сохранить":
        sql = 'EXEC [dbo].[BazaData] @Tovar=?,@Count=?,@Data=?'
        params = (values['-KTovar2-'], values['-KCountTovar-'], Datatime)
        dbCursor.execute(sql, params)
        dbCursor.commit()
        print(params)
    if event == "Обновить":
        values['-KTovar1-']=UpdateList()
    window.refresh()
```

все значения передаються и сохраняются в ms sql таблице. все работает хорошо, но интерфейс не обновляется

Comment: [https://github.com/Womba306/Test/tree/InterfaceTest1] для любителей гита

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновление списка значений элемента `Listbox` нужно делать так:

```py
window['-KTovar1-'].update(values=UpdateList())
```

Comment: `window.refresh()` надо делать?

Comment: `window.refresh()` делать не надо.

Comment: да все работает, я таб не проставил

Comment: Не знаешь как пофиксить баг с отображением значений с цыфрами в списке?

Comment: Непонятно в чем заключается баг и как выглядит. Пожалуйста, создайте новый вопрос, т. к. по теме текущего ответ дан.

Comment: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1295753/%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d1%8b%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5listbox-pysimplegui-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f] сможешь помочь?